# QGIS Report builder: Are there atlas-like syntaxes (like "@atlas_pagename" etc)?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts, atlas, reports

I'm just starting to use the Report-Feature in QGIS 3.20, with which I want to combine both single maps and altas-like mapsets in one step.

In the Atlas-Layout-Feature, I am able to use functions like `@atlas_pagename`, `@atlas_featurenumber` etc, which I used a lot for customizing each atlas page, for example:

```
WHEN (@atlas_totalfeatures)='7'
THEN '2020'
WHEN (@atlas_totalfeatures)='8'
THEN '2021'
WHEN (@atlas_totalfeatures)='9'
THEN '2022'
```

Or

```
WHEN @atlas_pagename = '2019'
THEN 'Januar - April '
WHEN  @atlas_pagename = '2020'
THEN 'November 2019 - März'
```

In the Report-Layout-Feature, I can't find anything corresponding to that functionality. Is it possible to achieve the same functionality?

- And as an extra-question: Is there a preview-function existing in the Report-Layout-Feature?

Answer (score 2):

For the test i have done to do report you can use the same variable the variable name stay the one used for atlas. At least i'm sure it work for `@atlas_feature` in a report.

I think it should work the same for :

- `@atlas_featurenumber`
- `@atlas_pagename`
- `@atlas_totalfeatures`

But you may pay attention : atlas_featurenumber and atlas_totalfeatures output number so it could not work well if you try to compare with a text (like in your example : `(@atlas_totalfeatures)='7'`)